# jQuery return value of deferred.then success when in function

Tags: jquery, deferred

I've written a function that I want to return the results of a successful deferred function. However, since the value I want returned is in the scope of the `doneCallbacks`, the `runSearch()` function returns undefined when running `console.log(runSearch())`. How can I have the containing function return the returned value of a successful `deferred.then()` ?

```
function runSearch(){   
    $.get( "search.php" ).then(
      function() {
        // I want runSearch() to return the results of this function 
      }, function() {
        console.log( "$.get failed!" );
      }
    );
}
```

**EDIT:** Thanks for all the help everyone. Since my goal was to user the return value in a function, I just included the function in the `doneCallbacks`.

```
function runSearch(){   
    $.get( "search.php" ).then(
      function() {
        var returnValue = 'Return Value'
        function doSomethingWithReturn(returnValue) {
            console.log(returnValue);
        }
        doSomethingWithReturn(returnValue);
      }, function() {
        console.log( "$.get failed!" );
      }
    );
}
runSearch(); // successfully logs returnValue to console.
```

May not be the most elegant solution, but works for this situation.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.   http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: What is your overall goal? Maybe we can achieve similar functionality.

Comment: Also I have never used this but have you tried $.ajax() syntax with async off? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I want to itterate over the results of the `$.get` function to build an object, which can then be used by another function outside of `runSearch()`

Comment: Are you trying to do it on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that.

Instead, you need to return the promise, then make all code that calls that function asynchronous, as well.

For more information see [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/).